Unable to launch a new process. when run laravel project under online windows server
i have laravel project and it working correctly under linux but i transfered it to windows server IIS then i face this issue
Unable to launch a new process.
$process = @proc_open($commandline, $descriptors, $this->processPipes->pipes, $this->cwd, $envPairs, $this->options);       
 if (!\is_resource($process)) {

            throw new RuntimeException('Unable to launch a new process.');       
 }        $this->process = $process;     
   $this->status = self::STATUS_STARTED;

notes : the same project was working under windows but i upgrade php from version 7 to 8 and update all necessary packages all site working but when i upload images i face this issue
i am trying to change upload folder permission and update composer

Windows/IIS is no more a friendly enough environment for PHP apps, https://docs.lextudio.com/phpmanager/getting-started/supported-platforms#php-on-windows-status You should stick to Linux.

or if is not in prod, use https://herd.laravel.com/windows

As Lex Li said, Microsoft no longer supports PHP on Windows/IIS. It is recommended that you still use Linux hosting.
